# How to write elegant string join condition to get full address property

Tags: asp.net, string

I am using `ASP .NET MVC (C#)`. Wondering how to write elegant condition for geting full address string from address elements. Final `FullAddress` string should be like this:

`"Street HouseNumber, ZIP City"`

For instance `"Krakonova 23, 12300 Prague"`

(But of course, the user can enter only the `City` too - full address is not required)

I have this model:

```
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNo { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }        
    public string FullAddress
    {
        get
        {
            string _fullAddress = null;
            // (...)
            return _fullAddress;
        }
}
```

---

For instance I am thinking about something like:

```
        get
        {
            string[] _addressPartOne = { this.Street, this.HouseNo };
            string[] _addressPartTwo = { this.Zip, this.City };
            string[] _addressFinal = { string.Join(" ", _addressPartOne.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))), string.Join(" ", _addressPartTwo.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))};
            string _fullAddress = string.Join(", ", _addressFinal.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
            return _fullAddress;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a string builder:

```
var _fullAddress = new StringBuilder();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Street)) _fullAddress.Append(Street);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseNo))
{
    if (_fullAddress.Length > 0) _fullAddress.Append(" ");
    _fullAddress.Append(HouseNo);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Zip))
{
    if (_fullAddress.Length > 0) _fullAddress.Append(", ");
    _fullAddress.Append(Zip);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))
{
    if (_fullAddress.Length > 0)
    {
        if (!_fullAddress.Contains(",")) _fullAddress.Append(",");
        _fullAddress.Append(" ");
    }
    _fullAddress.Append(City);
}    
return _fullAddress.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, but can you please write all the code? Beacause I think that after HouseNo condition will rapidly grow.

Comment: OK, edited. You could write a few unit tests for all the permutations you need to handle.

Comment: Thank you Steve. What you thing about my sugestion (in query)? It looks more simple but I am not sure about performance etc.

Comment: Definitely more than 1 way to do it. Depends on requirements, readability, etc. I use resharper which makes recommendations, but sometimes I ignore the lambda conversion because they make it less readable (IMO) in exchange for speed gains that don't matter for my app.